# Generate a report from oracle forms into PDF format

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have a report that I called from  Oracle Forms 6i.
My issue is that I want generate the report directly into a PDF format without demand me which output format I want.

below the code used to call and generate the report from Oracle forms (trigger WHEN_BUTTON_PRESSED):

```
DECLARE 
p_list PARAMLIST;
BEGIN
p_list :=CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST('TEMP');
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'PARAMFORM',TEXT_PARAMETER,'YES');
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'ep',TEXT_PARAMETER,':exer');
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'cc',TEXT_PARAMETER,':code');
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'op',TEXT_PARAMETER,':ordr');
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'nume',TEXT_PARAMETER,':nume');
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'DESTYPE',TEXT_PARAMETER,'SCREEN');
RUN_PRODUCT(REPORTS,'D:\Reports\MyReport6i.RDF',SYNCHRONOUS,RUNTIME,FILESYSTEM,p_list,null);
        IF NOT(ID_NULL(p_list)) THEN
DESTROY_Parameter_List(p_list);
END IF;
END;
```

Can you give more suggestions to generate the report into PDF file.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Set value `'FILE'` for parameter `DESTYPE` and add two more parameters:
DESFORMAT - format of output (PDF)
DESNAME - name of file

for example

```
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'DESTYPE',TEXT_PARAMETER,'FILE');    
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'DESFORMAT',TEXT_PARAMETER,'PDF');    
ADD_PARAMETER(p_list,'DESNAME',TEXT_PARAMETER,'c:\reports\myfile.pdf');
```